# Batch Script not parsing in IF Statment

Tags: batch-file, variables, if-statement, for-loop

I have a batch script to get the PC time and check if a text file is empty; if it is I manually enter a time in format `HR:MIN`; then I use `delims` to get individual variables for `HR` and for `MIN` and read them back as `HR:MIN` (just for testing purposes), but the script is returning just `:` without the variable values. I am sure it is something dumb I am missing but please give me your insight!

Here is the section of code:

```
for %%a in ("C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\%DAY%.txt") do set size=%%~za
if %size% EQU 0 (
    set /p Timeout=Time-Out: 
    echo %Timeout%>nul
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%i in ('echo %Timeout%') do set ToutHR=%%i
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('echo %Timeout%') do set ToutMIN2=%%i
    pause
    echo Time-Out: %ToutHR%:%ToutMIN2%
    pause
)
```

And then it returns:

```
C:\My Scripts>test.bat
Time-Now: 9:29
Time-Out: 4:45
Press any key to continue . . .
Time-Out: ECHO is on.:
Press any key to continue . . .
1 was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: yup have that, the header of my code is:@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
setlocal enableextensions

Comment: you also need to access your variables like `!Timeout!`,`ToutHR` ...

Comment: npocmaka, AND THERE IT IS i forgot i was parsing inside the loop!!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it in the header then change your code accordingly:

```bat
For %%a In ("C:\My Scripts\Temp Files\%DAY%.txt") Do Set "size=%%~za"

If "%size%"=="0" (Set/P "Timeout=Time-Out: "
    For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=:" %%i In ("!Timeout!") Do (Set "ToutHR=%%i"
        Set "ToutMIN2=%%j")
    Echo=Time-Out: !ToutHR!:!ToutMIN2!
    Pause
)
```

Comment: That is Def. Another (cleaner) way to do it :D but once i realized (thanks to @npocmaka) that since it was inside the if statement i needed to parse before the entire block was done and need to do use "!" vs "%" everything worked